# Unable to run app on device using android studio

Tags: error-handling, android-studio, dexopt

I have been trying to use android studio and every time I deploy an app on a device, it gives me an error saying:

```
Installation failed since the device possibly has stale dexed jars that don't match the current version (dexopt error).
```

In order to proceed, you have to uninstall the existing application.

I **have tried using Build->Clean Project** and yet it seems to do no good.
I **have also tried deleting the file from /data/local/tmp** on device (as my phone is a rooted one), but, all in vain.

If anyone knows a way out, please, please help.

Comment: what is the apk version of your application and your device ??

Comment: check http://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/574-can-t-deploy-apk-via-android-studio-stale-dexed-jars-install-failed-uid-changed

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the application from the device.
Check the storage space.
Once Restart the mobile and try to install it

Comment: the problem is that the application wasn't installed on my device :(

Comment: I uninstalled Android Studio and installed the latest version. It works good now ..Thanks :) :)